# I accidentally disabled the web interface for DD-WRT

Tags: embedded, router

I accidentally disabled the web interface for my DD-WRT router, but I can still SSH in. How can I fix it so I can admin with the GUI again?

Comment: How did you disable the gui?

Comment: I though I was disabling the remote access, but it was local :)

Comment: Answer from @charnley at http://superuser.com/a/263296 helped quite a lot. Also, I would suggest this question to be merged with the answers from [here](http://superuser.com/q/263295).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the dd-wrt wiki:](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface)

> If for some reason you completely lost
>   web access to the router, the web
>   server (HTTP daemon) may be shut down.
>   To regain access try starting the web
>   server. SSH or telnet into the router
>   and enter the following commands:

`httpd -h /www`

[This forum thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=29181) gives all to gory details about enabling/disabling the web interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can try restarting the [HTTP daemon](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Web_Interface#Regaining_Access) since you can still SSH in.  If that doesn't work, you may have to resort to a [full reset/reboot](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Reset_And_Reboot).

Comment: Ah nice. A reboot didn't work because it was diabled in the nvram. httpd -h /www worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite old question.

You can simply restart the HTTP daemon with:

```
startservice httpd
```